# ajax like/unlike product in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, bookmarks

I want to store like/unlike values in database through ajax in Laravel. I am new to Laravel and don't know how to store like/unlike values through ajax.
JavaScript code of like/unlike functionalities:

```
$('.like-icon, .widget-button, .like-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('liked');
    $(this).children('.like-icon').toggleClass('liked');
});
```

html code:

```
<span class="like-icon"></span>
```

here is ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('like') }}',
        data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'business_id': business_id
            'bookmark': (don't know what i should pass here?)
        },
        success: function() {
        }
    });
```

controller code:

```
$like = new Bookmark();
    $like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $like->business_id = $request->business_id;
    $like->bookmark = (don't know what i should pass here?) ;
    $like->save();
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/like', 'BookmarkController@index')->name('like');
```

please help to store values in database. I have three fields user_id, business_id, bookmark

If you guys anything wants to ask more please let me know.

Comment: I think your `bookmark` field is redundant. Simply having a record in the `bookmarks` table should suffice. If a `user` decides to unlike, delete the record.

Comment: what should i do now?